# C++ multi dimensional array of pointers without declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, global-variables

I want to declare multi dimensional (int his case two-dimensional) array. I can't declare size of global array. With one dimension, everything works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int N, M;
bool *table;

int main()
{
    ifstream in ("in.txt");
    in >> N >> M;

    table = new bool[N];

    return 0;
}
```

But if i want to declare two-dimensional array, I get an error:
**'M' cannot appear in a constant-expression**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int N, M;
bool **table;

int main()
{
    ifstream in ("in.txt");
    in >> N >> M;

    table = new bool[N][M];

    return 0;
}
```

What is my option apart from declaring number instead of N and M, creating vector array or declaring *table* in main function?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::vector` instead of worrying about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is my option apart from declaring number instead of N and M, creating vector array or declaring table in main function?

Allocate memory for `N` pointers.
For each pointer, allocate memory for `M` elements of type `bool`.

```
table = new bool*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
   table[i] = new bool[M];
}
```

When it's time to deallocate, use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
   delete [] table[i];
}

delete [] table;
```

You can avoid all the hassles of memory allocation and deallocation by using `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> table(N, std::vector<bool>(M));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the old way of doing things: allocate a unidimensional array and afterwards access it by the unique index by doing the calculation (i*N+j). If you want to hide it create a function with two parameters for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all the hassle of true multi-level arrays, you could:

```
int N=2, M=3;
bool *table = new bool[N*M];

// to access the element at (n,m):

ele = table[n*M + m];
```

This makes all the allocation/deallocation dead simple with the slight cost of having to type a bit more when accessing the elements. You could use a macro to fix that, of course.